How to remove main keyboard markup in telegram bot
I wanna remove ReplyKeyboardMarkup instance and show InlineKeyboardMarkup instead, but I just can't do this by simple way as reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove() because there is inserting new InlineKeyboardMarkup instance in code below
@dispatcher.message(Command("photo"))
async def send_random_photo(message: Message):
    await bot.send_photo(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        photo=random_photo_url,
        caption="Do you like this photo?)",
        reply_markup=photo_inline_keyboard,
)

How can I remove a ReplyKeyboardMarkup and then add an InlineKeyboardMarkup?

What telegram bot library do you use?

This is aiogram

Here's a possible straight forward approach.
(Edited)
You can remove the Keyboard with ReplyKeyboardRemove. But, you'll have to send an additional message to do that. So, send the initial placeholder message, something like "Here's a photo", along with the ReplyKeyboardRemove reply markup. And then, send the actual photo message with the inline reply markup.
I'm not familiar with Python, but if I'm correct, code will be something like:
@dispatcher.message(Command("photo"))
async def send_random_photo(message: Message):
    # Sending the initial message with ReplyKeyboardRemove
    await bot.sendMessage(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        text="Here's a photo",
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove(remove_keyboard=True),
    )

    await bot.send_photo(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        photo=random_photo_url,
        caption="Do you like this photo?",
        reply_markup=photo_inline_keyboard,
    )

Just an additional info.
If you want to send ReplyKeyboardMarkup such a way that whenever a button is pressed it should be immediately removed, you can set the one_time property on ReplyKeyboardMarkup to True. Check the documentation for ReplyKeyboardMarkup.one_time. If that's the case, you don't have to send ReplyKeyboardRemove along with the photo message, instead you can simply attach the photo_inline_keyboard itself.
Hope this helps!

I tried to edit my code as you suggested it, but variable photo_msg contains tuple of messages instead one message. What is this tuple represents?

Can you share the exact code you have rn, please? photo_msg shouldn't be a tuple, it should be the returned the sent Message object as per official docs. Can you also confirm the package/module you're using to build the bot?

You can see code here

I fixed this few minutes ago, but appeared new problem...  aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: message can't be edited

Oh no, seems like it's not working. It seems like ReplyKeyboardRemove cannot be edited. Sorry that I initially suggested that. At this point, I think you should send a temporary message containing ReplyKeyboardRemove reply markup and send the photo message with actual inline reply markup. Otherwise, you'll have to stick to the second option which is to create a one_time keyboard.

I've updated my original answer to reflect the working solution.
